# APK generada con React Native Expo no conecta al API de mi servidor de empresa

Tags: react-native, expo

espero se encuentren bien.

Actualmente me encuentro generando mi APK para una apicacion de React Native con Expo, pero una vez que genero el APK la aplicacion no logra establecer conexion con el API a pesar que la ruta funciona bien antes de generar el APK, se instalo el un certificado autofirmado en el servidor IIS para permitir una conexion HTTPS sin embargo, sigo sin poder conectar.

Alguna recomendacion o comentario de si es encesario aplicar alguna configuracion alternativa?

Saludos

Comment: A falta de saber cómo funciona exactamente Expo con respecto a android, revisa por un lado que el servidor es accesible desde el dispositivo (por ejemplo con el navegador web), y que en el manifest el certificado sea aceptado. https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config?hl=es-419#ConfigCustom

Comment: El API puede ser accesado desde el navegador, intenté conectarlo por medio de postman y genera una respuesta exitosa, he intentado solventar momentáneamente el problema utilizando ngrok para hacer el puerto publico, sin embargo esto me genera un riesgo de seguridad en el servidor, de conocer algún otro metodo agradezco mucho la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Hiciste lo de añadir el certificado al manifest de android?

Comment: Hola amigo, dentro del proyecto con Expo no se cuenta con la carpeta del manifest, sin embargo, configuré protocolos de seguridad en el servidor y expuse la ip y el puerto para que quedara de manera pública. De igual forma muchas gracias por la ayuda.